# puntero a struct anidada

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct alumno1{  
    int edad1;  
    float nota1;  
};    

struct alumno{
    int edad;  
    float nota;  
    struct alumno1 *alu1;
};


int main(int argc,char **argv){

   struct alumno *alu;

    alu=malloc(sizeof(alu));

    alu->alu1->edad1=12;
    printf("%i",alu->alu1->edad1);

    free(alu);  

    return 0;  
}
```

Me da error, en windows deja de funcionar y ubuntu el core dumped que creo que significa que esta accediendo a posiciones de memoria que no le corresponden gracias y un saludo

Comment: Que significa "no funciona". Da algun error o resultado inesperado?

Comment: Lo probe en windows y ubuntu, en windows deja de funcionar y en ubuntu lo mismo

Comment: Si hago malloc para alu1 no me deja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alu=malloc(sizeof(alu));
```

Esta instrucción está mal porque `alu` es un puntero y, en consecuencia `sizeof(alu)` te va a dar el tamaño de un puntero... no de una estructura. Lo correcto sería:

```
alu=malloc(sizeof(*alu));
```

Aun así tienes otro problema, y es que con la instrucción anterior estás reservando memoria para para la estructura `alumno`. Esta estructura tiene un puntero de tipo `alumno1`, pero la llamada a `malloc` no va a hacer una reserva adicional para este puntero... esa reserva tienes que hacerla a mano:

```
alu->alu1 = malloc(sizeof(struct alumno1)); // opcion 1
alu->alu1 = malloc(sizeof(*alu->alu1));     // opcion2
```

Por supuesto luego, a la hora de liberar la memoria, hay que hacerlo en orden inverso:

```
free(alu->alu1);
free(alu);
```

Comment: ya entendi gracias

Comment: Esto es lo que yo pensaba, pero mi c quedó enterrado en las arenas del tiempo y por eso eliminé mi comentario. Por curiosidad, serviría `alu->alu1 = malloc(sizeof(alu->alu1));`?

Comment: @Pikoh `alu->alu1` es equivalente a `sizeof(struct alumno1*)`...

Comment: Ok, ya veo. Trabajar con C# es lo que tiene :)

Comment: @Pikoh jajajaja ... en el fondo muchas cosas son iguales... pero los pequeños detalles marcan la diferencia

Comment: De todas maneras, `sizeof(alu)` tambien es equivalente a `sizeof(struct alumno*)`

Comment: Y porque al liberar la memoria hay que hacerlo en orden inverso?

Comment: @Pikoh bien visto

Comment: @Juan2005 porque si liberas `alu` ya no puedes garantizar que nadie sobreescriba el valor almacenado en `alu->alu1`. Si eso pasase perderías el puntero y no tendrías forma de liberar la memoira de `alu1`

Comment: ok gracias @eferion

Comment: Y yo, eso era lo que me extrañaba. Gracias crack ;)